# Change the same content of two iframes between two web pages with a click

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, click

I need to change the same content of two iframes between two web pages with a click. Like a powerpoint where you need to change to a new slide on two screens with only one click.

I hope you can give me the answer! 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with changing the content of one iframe, then it is fairly simple to do it on multiple iframes. If you are sure you will never need to change more than two iframes, then the simplest solution is to do something like this with Javascript:

```
// function that updates a single iframe
function updateIframe(iframe) {
  var iframeDocument = iframe.contentWindow.document;
  // iframeDocument is the iframe's document, so commands
  // like the ones below will work.
  // iframeDocument.appendChild();
  // iframeDocument.body.innerHTML = "<h1>Hello World</h1>";
}

// get the iframes from the DOM by their html id attribute
var iframe1 = document.getElementById('iframe1');
var iframe2 = document.getElementById('iframe2');

// bind a click event listener to the document body that
// will run updateIframe on both iframes
document.body.addEventListener('click', function() {
  updateIframe(iframe1);
  updateIframe(iframe2);
});
```

Comment: Will that solution work when it's between to web pages?

Comment: When I read your question, I took it that you meant you had two different webpages loaded into iframes on one webpage. If you are looking for something outside of the context of the webpage to change the webpage, then you'll need some kind of OS macro or application extension.